# The listing is incorrect

Tags: twig

can anyone please help me with this formula? It doesn't give me what I need. The first two posts to the active section, all the others to the inactive one.

```
    {% set memberLength = members|length / 2 %}
      {% for i in 1..memberLength %}
        {% set sliceStart = i * 2 - 2 %}
        {% set sliceLength = 2 %}
        {% if i < 2 %}
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="row m-0"> 
            {% for key, member in members|slice(sliceStart,sliceLength) %}
            <div class="col-lg-6 py-4 ps-lg-3 pe-lg-5 d-lg-block d-none">
                <div class="pb-4 mb-2 text-white">
                  <p class="fw-7 mb-0">{{ member.name }}</p>
                  <p>{{ member.podjmeno }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-primary PF fz-19">
                  <h2 class="fw-4 mb-3">{{ member.nadpisvelky }}</h2>
                  <p><em>{{ member.description }}</em></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="row m-0"> 
            {% for key, member in members|slice(sliceStart,sliceLength) %}
             <div class="col-lg-6 py-4 ps-lg-3 pe-lg-5 d-lg-block d-none">
                <div class="pb-4 mb-2 text-white">
                  <p class="fw-7 mb-0">{{ member.name }}</p>
                  <p>{{ member.podjmeno }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-primary PF fz-19">
                  <h2 class="fw-4 mb-3">{{ member.nadpisvelky }}</h2>
                  <p><em>{{ member.description }}</em></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Listing then:
     

             <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row m-0"> 
                </div>
      </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row m-0"> 
                </div>
      </div>

Comment: What's up with the slicing? You just want to show all members and set the first two to active right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a repeating HTML structure you are best off with using the filter [`batch`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/batch.html)

To set the class `active` on the first item you can use the attribute `first` of the [`loop`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) variable

```
{% for items in members|batch(2) %}
<div class="carousel-item{{ loop.first ? ' active' }}">
    {% for item in items %}
        <div class="col-lg-6 py-4 ps-lg-3 pe-lg-5 d-lg-block d-none">
            <div class="pb-4 mb-2 text-white">
              <p class="fw-7 mb-0">{{ item.name }}</p>
              <p>{{ item.podjmeno }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text-primary PF fz-19">
              <h2 class="fw-4 mb-3">{{ item.nadpisvelky }}</h2>
              <p><em>{{ item.description }}</em></p>
            </div>
          </div>    
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/0z28z5)